# How to get context value from normal function in react native ? ( Without useContext or class components)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My expectation scenario is as follows:
My app has two modes: called English and Arabic. So, The scenario is if mode is Arabic, I have to do {flexDirection:'row-reverse'}. So, my current approach is to check App mode and applying styles. So, I wrote a common function to that in separate file, which returns modified styles. But some Hooks constraints is not allowing to use 'useContext'. My snippet is giving error.

```
import {AppModeConsumer} from '../context/AppContext';
import {useContext} from 'react';

const styleFormat = style => {
  const mode = useContext(AppModeConsumer);
  console.log('MODE:', mode);
  if (mode === 'arabic') {
    if (style.flexDirection === 'row') {
      return Object.assign({}, style, {flexDirection: 'row-reverse'});
    }
  }
  return style;
};
```

Is there any alternative way to get that context Value?

Comment: "But some Hooks constraints is not allowing", is a warning? Can you tell us about what constraints you refer to

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the ["Rules of hooks"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) the only "constraint" that you may be talking about is a lint warning.

Custom hooks names have to be with `use` prefix:

```
const useStyleFormat = style => {...};
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really follow what the mean by

> But some Hooks constraints is not allowing to use 'useContext'

but anyhow consider one of those:

First, try change `styleFormat` to `useStyleFormat`. that way you are creating custom hook, maybe that way you gonna avoid some of illegal hooks operations.

Second, you can always declare `styleFormat` as `StyleFormat` component, that returns null

---

```
 import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
 import {AppModeConsumer} from '../context/AppContext';

 const StyleFormat = style => {
   const mode = useContext(AppModeConsumer);
   console.log('MODE:', mode);
   useEffect(()=> {
     if (mode === 'arabic' && style.flexDirection === 'row') 
       Object.assign({}, style, {flexDirection: 'row-reverse'});
  }, [mode]);

  return null //as for component UI presentation
 }
```

---

and use it as regular `<StyleFormat style={somePropStyle} />`